# How to obtain the parent product inside a template?

Tags: shopware6

for my shopware 6 app I want to obtain the parent product number by doing so:

```
{% set parentProduct = services.repository.search('product', { 'ids': [ page.product.parentId ] }).first %}
```

In the manifest.xml the permission to read products is also set:

```
<permissions>
    <read>product</read>
</permissions>
```

But this gives me null. What am I missing here?
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Did you set page like so `{% set page = hook.page %}`? Otherwise it should be `hook.page.product.parentId`.

Comment: No, but I am using {{ page.product.productNumber }} on the same template, which works fine.

Comment: Still try it in the repository method with the full path including `hook`. There might be some magic that resolves `page` when printing variables but not in functions.

Comment: hook.page.product does not work. And setting the varibale throws an error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "productId" for route "frontend.detail.page" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").

Comment: Now I see, that   {{ dump(services) }} is null. I am using this code inside the base.html.twig. Maybe the service is not available there?

Comment: I created an Action script for the product-page-loaded hook. The service is present there, which is not in a template twig file. Anyways, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> Now I see, that {{ dump(services) }} is null. I am using this code inside the base.html.twig. Maybe the service is not available there?

While app scripts also use twig syntax, they cannot be used in regular twig storefront templates.

Instead you have to place them in the dedicated directory for scripts inside your app's directory structure.

`MyFirstApp/Resources/scripts/product-page-loaded/my-first-script.twig`

`product-page-loaded` is just one of the [available hooks](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference) and by naming the directory correspondingly it indicates when the script is executed. Note that the available data and services may vary from hook to hook.